# Is it possible to pass data from one method to another in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got two methods within a controller.

```
public function can_add(){
    $desc = 'inventory';
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('employee_id');
    $data['roles'] = $this->priviledges_model->app_roles($desc);
    foreach ($data['roles'] as $role) {
        $role_id = $role['role_id'];
    }
    $data['member_role'] = $this->priviledges_model->empApp_roles($user_id, $role_id);
    foreach ($data['member_role'] as $role) {
        $can_add = $role['can_add'];
        $can_delete = $role['can_delete'];
    }
}
```

The challenge basically is to access variables declared in the above method in the method below. Thanks in anticipation.

```
public function newProduct(){
    $data['roles'] = $this->can_add();
    $data['title'] = 'New Product';
    $data['controller'] = $this->router->fetch_class();
    $data['parent'] = $this->menu_model->listMenuLevel1();
    $data['back'] = $this->load->view('menus/back', NULL, TRUE);
    $data['stocks'] = $this->inventory_model->stocks();
    $data['product'] = $this->branches_model->getall();
    $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('menus/inventory', $data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('folder/page', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve what you want to achieve? Why do you think that this should not work?

Comment: Are they in the same class?

Comment: Which variables do you want to see in both methods?

Comment: One way, return value from one method and pass to second as a param

Comment: Another method: Make the variable a class property, then you can use it in many methods using `$this->something`

Comment: You call `$data['roles'] = $this->can_add();` but your not returning from that method.

Comment: As you are doing this `$data['roles'] = $this->can_add();` then you definitely need to RETURN something from `can_add()` as you are attempting to capture a returned value already

Comment: @ RiggsFolly yeah, they are in the same class and I want to access $can_add = $role['can_add']; $can_delete = $role['can_delete'];

Comment: See previous comment to yours

Comment: What you return rather depends upon what you will be doing with `$data['roles']` in your view

Comment: What best should be done @ Lawrence Cherone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function can_add(){
        $desc = 'inventory';
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('employee_id');
        $data['roles'] = $this->priviledges_model->app_roles($desc);
        foreach ($data['roles'] as $role) {
            $role_id = $role['role_id'];   
        }
        $data['member_role'] = $this->priviledges_model->empApp_roles($user_id, $role_id);
            foreach ($data['member_role'] as $roles) {
                $data['can_add'] = $roles['can_add'];
                $data['can_update'] = $roles['can_update'];
            }
        return $data;

    }
```

I have been able to access values declared in the above method in the method below.

```
public function newProduct(){
        $user_privileges = $this->can_add();
        $can_add = $user_privileges['can_add'];
        $can_edit = $user_privileges['can_edit'];
        //

        $data['title'] = 'New Product';
        $data['controller'] = $this->router->fetch_class();
        $data['parent'] = $this->menu_model->listMenuLevel1();
        $data['back'] = $this->load->view('menus/back', NULL, TRUE);
        $data['stocks'] = $this->inventory_model->stocks();
        $data['product_types'] = $this->inventory_model->productTypes();
        $data['menu'] = $this->load->view('menus/inventory', $data, TRUE);


        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('folder/page', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create some "properties" in your class. Use the `$this` keyword to access it.

```
<?php

class RandomClass
{
    protected $sharedVar;

    public function methodOne()
    {
        $this->sharedVar = 5;
    }

    public function methodTwo()
    {
        $this->sharedVar ++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is easy. All you need to do is have `can_add()` return something. This code implies that you expect it to.

```
public function newProduct(){
        $data['roles'] = $this->can_add();
        ...
```

But, in your code `can_add()` **does not** return anything. In `newProduct()` the value assigned to `$data['roles']` is going to be null.

It isn't clear exactly what you need from `can_add()`. I'll make a guess.
The code that follows returns an indexed `array` where each item's value is an array with the keys `can_add` and `can_delete`.

```
public function can_add()
{
    $desc = 'inventory';
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('employee_id');
    $roles = $this->priviledges_model->app_roles($desc);
    foreach ($roles as $role)
    {
        $member_roles = $this->priviledges_model->empApp_roles($user_id, $role['role_id']);
        foreach ($member_roles as $role)
        {
            $data[] = array($role['can_add'], $role['can_delete']);
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The above is an example of a "bad practice". As a rule "best practices" say that you should not make database queries in a loop which is exactly what happens with the call

```
$member_roles = $this->priviledges_model->empApp_roles($user_id, $role['role_id']);
```

It's hard to know for sure, but my hunch is that a model method could be devised that would return the same results without having to use two models or resort to database calls in a loop. There seems to be a relationship between two (or more) tables that a well-designed query easily handle. But that would be best explored in another question.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer gave me a very clear understanding of what I wanted. If you checked my codes, my query was not in a loop. I have been able from your answer to resolve my challenge

Comment: I was saying how **my** code was bad practice, not yours. :) Happy you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access variables defined in another function you have to use Global variables THOUGH THIS IS NOT GOOD PRACTICE. So if you want to access variable in multiple functions you should declare it inside class like protected `$definedVar = "Something"` than you can access this variable inside another function like

```
function useDefinedVariable(){
    return $this->definedVar * 100;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If both methods are in the same class/same controller, just put all the parameters of the first method you need to pass on to the second one inside an array and invoke the second one:

```
$params = array( 'a' => 'something', 'b' => 'some other thing's);
$this->second_method($params);
```

This only works if both methods are in the same class